# SharePoint - List Column Behaving as mandatory

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a list which was migrated from SharePoint On premise to SharePoint Online.
List has content types.
There is a single line of text column called "Project Number" which is "optional" at content type level but when i try to create a new item. It does not let me submit the item if Project Number is empty.
List forms are out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to list settings-> click "Project Number" column, then set "Enforce unique values:" to "No".
2. If it already set to "No", check if some custom code(like JavaScript) in the NewForm.aspx page.
3. Create a new list and add the content type, then check if it works.